# Dealing with asynchronous error handling

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I am creating a WeatherService class for my app-project and I have been reading about error handling in Swift 2.0 the past days.

From what I have read I have come up with a class like this:

```
enum ResultType<T, U> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(U)
}
```

My weather forecast lookup method looks like this (it is asynchronous!):

```
func weatherForecastFor(location location: Location, completionHandler: (ResultType<WeatherForecast, WeatherServiceError>) -> Void) {...}
```

The view controller that uses the `WeatherService` class looks like this:

```
self.weatherService.weatherForecastFor(location: location) {
(result: ResultType<WeatherForecast, WeatherServiceError>) -> Void in

switch result {
case .Success(let weatherForecast): // some code here.
case .Error(let error):
switch error {
    case .InvalidLocation:
    // Does something
    case .LocationNotFound:
    // Does something
}
}                                                        
}
```

From what I have been reading this seems to be how many suggest handling errors in asynchronous methods in Swift at the moment, but please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

The thing I wonder how to do is; inside the weather service I use `NSXMLParser` and `NSURLSession` they both have a delegate that I adhere to. And they both pass error objects either from delegate method or completion handler like this:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {...}
```

My question is: How should I deal with the parse error for instance? Should the ResultType I made contain this error? The user is unable to do anything about a parse error, and I can't handle that in an another way than telling the user that weather forecast lookup failed. Should I extract some error details from this parseError and wrap that in one of my own WeatherServiceError?

Doing this inside the method doesn't tell the surrounding code why it failed:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        self.completionHandler(ResultType.Error(WeatherServiceError.SomethingFailedSillyError))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do basically the same as you do except I would tend to use OO style more than a functional style:

```
let dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
let dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()

var result: String?

enum WeatherForecast {
    case Success(Forecast)
    case InvalidLocation
    case LocationNotFound
    func handle() {
        switch self {
        case .Success(_): result = "Success"
        case .InvalidLocation: result = "InvalidLocation"
        case .LocationNotFound: result = "LocationNotFound"
        }
    }
}

func weatherForecastFor(location _: Location) {
    dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatchQueue) {
        WeatherForecast.InvalidLocation.handle() // In reality process location then call handle()
    }
}

weatherForecastFor(location: Location())
dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
print(result)
```